# save function in array, and then check it, but always return -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript function like this (i use jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = [];

    function addArray(item) {
        var alreadyIn = jQuery.inArray(item, arr);

        alert("already in : " + alreadyIn);

        if (alreadyIn == -1) {
            alert("going to push it")
            arr.push(item);
            alert("after push : " + arr)
        }
    }

    addArray(function(mgs) {
        alert("hai 1");
    });

    addArray(function(mgs) {
        alert("hai 1");
    });
});
```

why is when i call the second addArray, the jQuery.inArray always return -1 ? which suppose not (because at the first time i already add that array )

is there something that i did wrong here ??

Comment: You're pushing two separate and unique function objects into the Array. To push the same function, you'll need to reference it first, then push it both times. http://jsfiddle.net/BkEW4/

Comment: The functions are anonymous, so `.inArray` will never be true. If you did `var x = function...` and pushed, that may work.

Comment: The trouble isn't really that they're anonymous. The trouble is that they're unique.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Isn't that the same thing though? Anonymous functions are always unique

Comment: @Ian: No. Two ways to look at it. First, if you give the functions names, they're not anonymous, but it still won't give the desired result. Second is that you could change the second call to `arr.push(arr[0]);`, so now you're pushing the same (non-unique) anonymous function, and it'll give the desired result.

Comment: @CrazyTrain That should be an answer. I'm also convinced this is the issue OP is having - he's pushing two functions who just happen to do the same thing.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: My answers are usually in the form of comments. I'll let someone else harvest rep. :-)

Comment: @CrazyTrain OP's question is valid - and your answer solves his issue. If what's bothering you is the rep you can always post as community wiki - you don't get rep and also other people can edit useful stuff in easily.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Lately I do leave a wiki if the answer can't fit into a comment (usually because lengthy code is needed). Yes, the question is valid. Didn't mean to suggest it wasn't

Comment: @CrazyTrain I don't understand either of your points. The OP **expects** them to be the "same" function because they have the same contents. When you give the two functions names, they're no longer anonymous and is no longer related to this question. All anonymous functions are unique. So are 2 **different** (named) functions. And your second point doesn't make sense because you're not pushing the **same** anonymous function - you're pushing a reference (just like your first comment here), so that was kind of confusing. Not trying to be annoying, just trying to get the right wording

Comment: @Ian The problem is the term "anonymous function" is not well defined in the specification (nor does it even appear there). I think CrazyTrain means function expression, and you think of any function that's never assigned to any identifier.

Comment: @Ian: I wasn't commenting on OP's expectations. Only on the comment. I'm just saying that the issue has nothing to do with anonymity. If the functions did have names, it still wouldn't work. And the inverse is that it will work given a change to the code even though we still have an anonymous function. Anonymity has nothing to do with what's causing the unexpected result.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Almost. We can have non-anonymous (named) function expressions. The issue at play is that two unique objects are being created, and object equality is always a matter of identity.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yeah I think I'm overthinking this and focusing on the wrong thing. We all seem to understand the problem (except the OP originally), so I'll just leave it at that, and stop trying to confuse us all - the problem is that the functions are unique, and Kolink's answer should help explain better :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Interesting point on the term "anonymous function" not being in the spec though. I've never bothered to look.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yeah, names function expressions are just function expressions (I think I've actually discussed this with Ian before), the main advantages are in recursion and debugging. Still, there is no (external) identifier to them making them (how clever!) named anonymous functions. Got to love the naming in the ECMAScript wiki :)

Comment: thanks guys for answering it.. now i understand why it doesnt work.. thanks also crazy train for the example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are only equal to each other (and therefore only trigger an `inArray` check) if they are the exact same *instance* of the object.

For example:

```
var a = {}, b = {}, c = a;
a == b // false, different instances
a == c // true, same instance
```

Your two functions may be identical, but they are still two functions, not the same one.

Comment: Yes. He may try to assign the function to a variable and then call addArray mutliple times with that same variable as arg.

Comment: Worth mentioning - this happens for functions too (like in OP's case) since in JavaScript functions are also objects. [`inArray`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.inArray) uses the identity operator (`===`) which indeed [checks if the objects are the same reference](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6), and I quote `Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.`